# Make an algorithm start again?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, if-statement

So I'm pretty new to coding with Java (started yesterday). What I am trying to do is to make an Input of an Integer, if the **int c** it is higher than 1 or lower than 0 (if it is not 1 or 0), I want it to start again. If **int c** equals either 1 or 0, I want the alogrithm to continue. I tried to insert some kind of loops after **if(c > 1 || c < 0)** but it does not seem to work and only spams my console with the result. Is there any easy way to make the algorithm start over again? I'm already trying to fix this for more than 2 hours, but I'm just confusing me over and over again.

```
// more code up here but it is unimportant
int c = sc.nextInt();

    if(c > 1 || c < 0) {
        result = result + wrong;
        System.out.println(result);
    } else if (c == 1) {
        result = result + notImplemented;
        System.out.println(result);
    } else if (c == 0) { //more code follows here but is unimportant
```

Comment: "again" - re-use it... put it in a method and call it again

Comment: @lolo I do not want to call the whole method again, since there is more stuff going on on top. Thank you though, should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to ask for input again, i assume.

A simple way could be:

```
int c = sc.nextInt();

while (c > 1 || c < 0) {
    c = sc.nextInt();
}
//code continues
```

Comment: But then he doesn't print the messages anymore

Comment: Hey, yeah I had some problems with the messages but could fix it with: 
`if(c > 1 || c < 0) {

   while (c > 1 || c < 0) {

    System.out.println("No 0 or 1, try again: ");
    c = sc.nextInt();
   }
  }`

works now, thank you alot :)

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. Please mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasNextInt()` and a `while` loop to iterate over the data:

```
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    int aInt = sc.nextInt();
    //logic here
}
```

Documentation for `hasNextInt()` method:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop so you have

```
while(true){
    int c = sc.nextInt();

    if(c > 1 || c < 0) {
        result = result + wrong;
        System.out.println(result);
        break;
    } else if (c == 1) {
        result = result + notImplemented;
        System.out.println(result);
    } else if (c == 0) { //more code follows here but is unimportant
    ...
}
```

Since you say you are new, I'll do a little explanation:
A While loop repeats what is in it's code block (i.e within the `{ }`) for as long as a certain condition is true. In the case of my answer I did `while(true)` meaning it will keep repeating until something causes it to stop. In this case I used a `break` which forces the loop to end/stop.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I tried to implement a while(true) { } loop, but it does not work the way I want it to work. I managed to solve the problem though. First I check, if c is not equal to either 1 or 0 and if it is not, then I loop as long as c is not equal 1 or 0 and reset c to the next Integer as Input. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` in this case and use `break` to exit:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  int c = sc.nextInt();

    if(c > 1 || c < 0) {
        result = result + wrong;
        System.out.println(result);
    } else if (c == 1) {
        result = result + notImplemented;
        System.out.println(result);
        break;
    } else if (c == 0) {
       ...
       break;
    }
}

scanner.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put your code in a function (which I hope is already the case) and then when you don't have the expected result and want to call it again, just do so by calling your function inside itself.

It's called recursion.
You can learn more [here](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/) .
For example :

```
// more code up here but it is unimportant
public void myFunction(){
    int c = sc.nextInt();
    if(c > 1 || c < 0) {
        result = result + wrong;
        System.out.println(result);
    } else if (c == 1) {
        result = result + notImplemented;
        System.out.println(result);
    } else if (c == 0) { //more code follows here but is unimportant
    }
    //You want to call your function again
    myFunction();
}
```

Comment: I do not want to call the whole method again, since there is more stuff going on on top. Thank you, should've mentioned that. I do not know, why this has been downvoted, though.